# Display Items in Collection that Do Not Exist In Shopping Cart Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to iterate over items in the shopping cart and generate an upsell div with products NOT in the cart. Below is the code I have so far, but I run into issues when adding two items to cart running the loop twice generating the html twice. Any ideas on how to resolve it? I'm stumped.

```
{% for item in cart.items %} // iterates over items in cart

  {% if item.product.id == 4456879040188 %} // checks if product id matches in item in cart
    <div class="upsell-pop" style="text-align:center; width: 100%;">
      <h4>Frequently bought together</h4>
      {% for prod in collections.upsell.products %} // iterates products in collection upsell
        {% unless prod.handle contains "product-name" %} // shows only prods that do not contain url handle
            <div>
              <span class="upsell-title">{{ prod.title }}</span>
              <span class="upsell-price">{{ prod.metafields["meta"]["promo"] }} {{ prod.price | money }}</span>
              <a href="{{prod.url}}"><img src="{{ prod.featured_image | img_url: '200x' }}" /></a>
              <a class="btn-product" href="{{prod.url}}">View Product</a>
            </div>
        {% endunless %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Another thought is to somehow check to see if product is NOT in cart items inside to replace the existing "unless" statement, but not sure how to code it.

```
{% unless cart.items exist then %} // I know this is not correct syntax
     <div>
          <span class="upsell-title">{{ prod.title }}</span>
          <span class="upsell-price">{{ prod.metafields["meta"]["promo"] }} {{ prod.price | money }}</span>
          <a href="{{prod.url}}"><img src="{{ prod.featured_image | img_url: '200x' }}" /></a>
          <a class="btn-product" href="{{prod.url}}">View Product</a>
      </div>
{% endunless %}
```

Comment: No one can answer the question? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my mind, there are two steps here.

First, capture your cart content to get string to compare to when you loop through your upsell collection. This could be something like that:

```
{%- capture cart_items -%}
  {% for item in cart.items %}
    {{ item.product.handle }}{% unless forloop.last %} , {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{%- endcapture -%}
```

Then loop through your collection while checking your string does not contain the handle of the current product at each iteration:

```
{% for product in collections['upsell'].products %}
  {% unless cart_items contains product.handle %}
    {{ product.title }}
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Remarks:

Snippet 1 => In line_item (here called item because it's shorter to write) object you may access product object attributes: item.product.product_attr_needed

Snippet 2 => To access directly a collection object using its handle you must use collections + square brackets containing collection handle + attribute. Here 'upsell' is the handle of your upsell collection.

Not tested but this should work.

HTH